# Oracle Stored Procedure into a View

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a SP in oracle which returns a cursor, before I had a query to create a view, but due to the complexity of the data I need, the better option to get it was a SP, but I strictly need the view with the information (client's requirement), but now I have no idea how to put/convert the data (cursor) in the view, I was checking Global Temporary Tables, but that means I need to call the SP before accessing the view, and that's not possible. It's imperative that I call access the view with a select, `Select * from view_data_sp`, and obviously that the performance is not affected.

Any idea how can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider using record type, table of records and pipe rows. Something like this would do the trick?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE package sysop as
  type file_list_rec is record(filename varchar2(1024));
  type file_list is table of file_list_rec;

  function ls(v_directory varchar2) return file_list pipelined;
end;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE package body sysop as
  function ls(v_directory varchar2) return file_list pipelined is
    rec file_list_rec;
    v_host_list varchar2(32000) := '';
  begin
    v_host_list := host_list(v_directory);

    for file in (
      select regexp_substr(v_host_list, '[^'||chr(10)||']+', 1, level)
        from dual
          connect by
            regexp_substr(v_host_list, '[^'||chr(10)||']+', 1, level) is not null)
      loop
        pipe row (file);
      end loop;
     return;
  end ls;
end sysop;
/
```

Comment: Thanks you Mikolas, I'm gonna try this, but I do have a question, is there any implication in the performance? Because each time the view is queried the whole process is done, including the loop and calling the SP?

Comment: I'm not aware about any possible performance bottlenecks. Once the query is well written. The overhead is just the price for flexibility.